# How can configure linux routing to send packets out one interface, over a bridge and into another interface on the same box

Tags: linux, networking, routes

I'm trying to test a ethernet bridging device.  I have multiple ethernet ports on a linux box.  I would like to send packets out one interface, say eth0 with IP 192.168.1.1, to another interface, say eth1 with IP 192.168.1.2, on the same subnet.

I realize that normally you don't configure two interfaces on the same subnet, and if you do the kernel routes directly to each interface, rather than over the wire.  How can I override this behavior, so that traffic to 192.168.1.2 goes out the 192.168.1.1 interface, and visa-versa?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This question is ill-suited to SO.  But I'll take a stab anyways: use a NAT somewhere in the chain and you may be able to accomplish this.  (not a traditional SNAT btw)

Answer (score 2):

This is a guess, but I hope it is in the right direction.

Make more-specific routing table entries, along the lines of:

```
route add -host 192.168.1.2 dev eth0
route add -host 192.168.1.1 dev eth1
```

[You may also need to fiddle with the `accept_local` configuration](http://www.gremwell.com/linux-routing-quirks) for both interfaces -- or the `all` setting. (Turning this on may make your machine more susceptible to IP source spoofing attacks; be sure you have good ingress firewall rules elsewhere to prevent trouble.) (See `sysctl -a | grep accept_local` for what I'm talking about.)

Comment: I think the accept_local parameter is the key.  I will report back

Comment: Any luck? If this isn't it, please flag your question and ask a moderator to migrate it to [SF]. (I think it is also on-topic here, but the SF audience may know the kernel tunables better.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like Mac-Vlan in your Linux. This cannot be done with NAT only. Read this: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/7268.