# accept_local doesn't work

Tags: linux, local, routes

I want send out data from one NIC and received by another NIC on a CENTOS6.4( X86 frame ,3 NIC, one is onboard realtek's, the other two is intel NICs ).

First,I configured intel nic ip: (eth0) 192.168.1.1/24 and (eth1) 192.168.1.2/24 on two intel NICs.

Second, I add route by following cmds:

```
# route add -host 192.168.1.1 dev eth1
# route add -host 192.168.1.2 dev eth0
```

Third, I enabled accept_local in /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.accept_local = 1
net.ipv4.conf.eth1.accept_local = 1
```

And I also disabled iptables and SElinux. I reboot the system, then use a wire connect eth0 and eth1, then I test like this:

```
#ping 192.168.1.1 -I eth1
```

Message returned:

```
"From 192.168.1.2 icmp_seq=xx Destination Host Unreachable"
```

Has I missed something?

I have read this topic [How can configure linux routing to send packets out one interface, over a bridge and into another interface on the same box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679814/how-can-configure-linux-routing-to-send-packets-out-one-interface-over-a-bridge/11680024#11680024) already.

Comment: `dmesg | grep eth` tells you that both eth's link layer is up?

Comment: Yes , both eth0 and eth1 is up as posted below.  e1000: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX e1000: eth1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX/TX .

Comment: Is there other ways to accomplish such feature?

Answer (score 4):

try set `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=2`

Refer https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.txt

```
accept_local - BOOLEAN
    Accept packets with local source addresses. In combination
    with suitable routing, this can be used to direct packets
    between two local interfaces over the wire and have them
    accepted properly.

    rp_filter must be set to a non-zero value in order for
    accept_local to have an effect.


rp_filter - INTEGER
    0 - No source validation.
    1 - Strict mode as defined in RFC3704 Strict Reverse Path
        Each incoming packet is tested against the FIB and if the interface
        is not the best reverse path the packet check will fail.
        By default failed packets are discarded.
    2 - Loose mode as defined in RFC3704 Loose Reverse Path
        Each incoming packet's source address is also tested against the FIB
        and if the source address is not reachable via any interface
        the packet check will fail.

    Current recommended practice in RFC3704 is to enable strict mode
    to prevent IP spoofing from DDos attacks. If using asymmetric routing
    or other complicated routing, then loose mode is recommended.

    The max value from conf/{all,interface}/rp_filter is used
    when doing source validation on the {interface}.

    Default value is 0. Note that some distributions enable it
    in startup scripts.
```